# Can I use my USB OTG keyboard and the software keypad at the same time on my android phone?

Tags: android, keyboard, smartphone

I am having a Lenovo Phab Plus running android lollipop and I was developing an app that reads an RFID tag, The RFID tag reader can be connected to the android device and it is treated like a usb otg keyboard. The problem is whenever I connect the RFID reader the phone's software keypad doesn't pop up, as the adroid thinks that there is actually another physical keyboard connected.
Is there a way to use both the software keypad and the RFID reader (or a USB OTG keyboard) at the same time? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I try that in my galaxy s4 and both the software keypad and the USB OTG keyboard worked at the same time . I think your problem is some thing else